# Cannot find the WebElements with Selenium that I can see from the Chrome browser's inspect window

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit-driver

**Edit:** It works with the chrome driver but not with HtmlUnitDriver, why?

I am trying to get WebElements with classname = "cat-pick_i"

I can see these elements in Chrome's inspect window as seen here [image: Inspect window output]

My code is as follows,

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

    driver.get("https://amzscout.net/sales-estimator");
    System.out.println("Title : "+driver.getTitle());

    WebElement pickList = driver.findElement(By.className("cat-pick_list"));
    System.out.println(pickList.toString());

    List<WebElement> elements = pickList.findElements(By.className("cat-pick_i"));
    System.out.println("num of categories : "+elements.size());

    for (int i = 0; i <elements.size() ; i++) {
        WebElement element = elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("cat-pick_name-in"));
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
```

And the output of my code is as follows,

```
Title : Amazon Products Sales History Estimator, Rank Calculator | AMZScout
<div class="cat-pick_list" />
num of categories : 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**My question is** why can't I get those WebElements and how could I get them.

Edit: There are also warnings from **HtmlUnitDriver** that might be helpful

```
    Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:4132] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:4162] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:7255] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:7276] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:11589] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:11609] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:11723] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:11744] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:12259] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:12280] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:23006] Error in @media rule. (Invalid token "@font-face". Was expecting one of: <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ".", ":", "*", "[", <HASH>, <IMPORT_SYM>, <PAGE_SYM>, <MEDIA_SYM>, <ATKEYWORD>.)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:23006] Ignoring the whole rule.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:23135] Error in rule. (Invalid token "}". Was expecting one of: <S>, <IDENT>, "<!--", "-->", ".", ":", "*", "[", <HASH>, <IMPORT_SYM>, <PAGE_SYM>, <MEDIA_SYM>, <FONT_FACE_SYM>, <ATKEYWORD>.)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [1:23135] Ignoring the whole rule.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://amzscout.net/css/common.css' [2:45659] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <UNICODE_RANGE>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:30 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:31 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:32 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: application/ld+json, language: ). Skipping execution.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:33 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet isValidCondition
WARNING: Unhandled CSS condition type 'PREFIX_ATTRIBUTE_CONDITION'. Accepting it silently.
Oct 29, 2018 6:22:33 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName=[https://amzscout.net/js/common.js] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be more specific of your search criteria, there is two div that have class name: 'cat-pick_list', and the second one is empty.

*Note:*
*start using css selectors and xpath(only if css selector does not help), best option will be id.*

Try with

```
WebElement pickList = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".container > .cat-pick_list"));
.....
List<WebElement> elements = pickList.findElements(By.cssSelector(".cat-pick_i"));
```

Result:

> num of categories : 30 Appliances Arts, Crafts & Sewing Automotive
>   Baby Beauty & Personal Care Books Camera & Photo Cell Phones &
>   Accessories Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry Computers & Accessories
>   Electronics Grocery & Gourmet Food Health & Household Home and Garden
>   Home & Kitchen Industrial & Scientific Jewelry Kindle Store Kitchen &
>   Dining Musical Instruments Office Products Patio, Lawn & Garden Pet
>   Supplies Shoes Software Sports & Outdoors Tools & Home Improvement
>   Toys & Games Watches Video Games

Comment: I am still getting the same result even though I have used the cssSelectors you gave. Can the problem be caused by something different ?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this directly:

```
List<WebElement> elements = pickList.findElements(By.cssSelector(".container > .cat-pick_list > .cat-pick_i"));
```

I think this should work.